# Find and replace string in a tree. Recursive

Tags: linux, windows, recursion, sed, rename

I have tried searching for answer here and I found some but they dont seem to work for me. I want to rename a project file and I find it that the esiest way would be to replace its name in every single file and ALSO every file name as well in the directory.

Could someone please point me a way (in windows or linux) to replace recursively a string in a directory in every file and every file name, with another string?

I would appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

## **Bash**

In Unix you can do it in bash shell. You have to make use of **find**, **mv** and **sed** and the following three commands as examples:

1. Replace string *"ABC"* with *"345"* in the *name of every directory*
   in the current directory or in the subdirectories recursively.

   ```
   find . -depth -type d -name "*ABC*" -exec bash -c 'dir=${1%/*} base=${1##*/}; mv "$1" "$dir/${base//ABC/345}"' par0 {} \;
   ```
2. Replace string *"ABC"* with *"345"* in the *name of every file* in
   the current directory or in the subdirectories recursively.

   ```
   find . -depth -type f -name "*ABC*" -exec bash -c 'dir=${1%/*} base=${1##*/}; mv "$1" "$dir/${base//ABC/345}"' par0 {} \;
   ```
3. Replace string *"ABC"* with *"345"* in the *content of every file*
   in the current directory or in the subdirectories recursively.

   ```
   find . -depth -type f -name "*" -exec bash -c 'sed -i "s/ABC/345/g" "$1"' par0 {} \;
   ```